# Error serializing DataSet to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dataset, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize a `DataSet` to an **XML** file.
As can be seen from the sample output all of my tables have names and the dataset is named as well. The dataset namespace is "", changing this had no effect.
The exception being caught is is:

> Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.

As you can see below quite clearly, all the tables have been named.

```
DataSet Name: TestDataSet
Table:        TABLE1
Table:        TABLE2
Table:        TABLE3
Table:        TABLE4
Table:        TABLE5
```

> Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.

Here is the code I am using to serialize the dataset:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("db.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    stream.Close();
}
```

if the `XmlWriteMode` is `WriteSchema` the xml file is created and is populated with the schema, the exception is still thrown. If the `XmlWriteMode` is `IgnoreSchema` and empty file is created and the exception is thrown.

What is causing this problem? I have trawled through loads of postings here and elsewhere on the web and everyone says "set the table name". I have done this but it makes no difference.

Comment: Past a db.xml. No all lines, just some data.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code where you generate your dataset, you must provide this code or a sample (mockup) of it which generates the same error.

Comment: I think I have figured out what the problem is. The data is being deserialized from JSON into the dataset using JSON.NET. One of the columns in some of the tables has it's type set to DataTable. I think it is these columns which the the serializer does not know how to handle. Does this make sense?

Comment: DataSet is created thus: DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem is due to some tables in the Dataset not given a Name. it is probably secondary tables (table elements inside the Table1, Table2 etc).

The Solution could be to *Iterate* through all objects in the Dataset and, if type is DataTable set a generic name.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome, I would have provided the snippet code to do the iteration as well, so to help you further, but I see now you made it already. Nice, I upvoted you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have employed and it works.
Probably not the most efficient but the XML is now serialized correctly.

```
    private void FixTables(DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                var columnName = column.ColumnName;
                if (column.DataType == typeof(DataTable) && row[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    DataTable innerTable = (DataTable)row[columnName];
                    innerTable.TableName = columnName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```